# Powershell equivalent of python's if __name__ == '__main__':

Tags: python, powershell, language-comparisons

I am really fond of python's capability to do things like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #setup testing code here
    #or setup a call a function with parameters and human format the output
    #etc...
```

This is nice because I can treat a Python script file as something that can be called from the command line but it remains available for me to import its functions and classes into a separate python script file easily without triggering the default "run from the command line behavior".

Does Powershell have a similar facility that I could exploit?  And if it doesn't how should I be organizing my library of function files so that i can easily execute some of them while I am developing them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$MyInvocation` has lots of information about the current context, and those of callers. Maybe this could be used to detect if a script is being dot-sourced (i.e. imported) or executed as a script.

A script can act like a function: use `param` as first non-common/whitespace in the file to defined parameters. It is not clear (one would need to try different combinations) what happens if you dot-source a script that starts `param`...

Modules can directly execute code as well as export functions, variables, ... and can take parameters. Maybe `$MyInvocation` in a module would allow the two cases to be detected.

EDIT: Additional:

`$MyInvocation.Line` contains the command line used to execute the current script or function. Its `Line` property has the scrip text used for the execution, when dot-sourcing this will start with "`.`" but not if run as a script (obviously a case to use a regex match to allow for variable whitespace around the period).

In a script run as a function

Comment: So something along the lines of:
if (! $MyInvocation.Line.Trim().StartsWith(". ")) { 
    #Scripty type invocation happens here
}

Comment: @MarkMascolino: after a quick test, can have `.<tab>script`, not just a space. I would use `-match '^\s+\.\s+'`.

Answer (score 8):

`$MyInvocation.Invocation` has information about how the script was started.

```
If ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq '&') {
    "Called using operator: '$($MyInvocation.InvocationName)'"
} ElseIf ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq '.') {
    "Dot sourced: '$($MyInvocation.InvocationName)'"
} ElseIf ((Resolve-Path -Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName).ProviderPath -eq $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) {
    "Called using path: '$($MyInvocation.InvocationName)'"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now I see 2 options that work

```powershell
if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -ne '.') {#do main stuff}
```

and

```powershell
if ($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq 'Runspace') {#do main stuff}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is only tested on Powershell Core on Linux. It may not work the same for Windows. If anyone tries it on Windows I would appreciate if you could verify in the comments.

```
function IsMain() {
  (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope Local).Value.PSCommandPath -Eq (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope Global).Value.InvocationName
}
```

[Demonstrated with a gist](https://gist.github.com/nathanchere/ef6a798f807a45a72b1b8e9eefcbe5f7)

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 10 VM, $PSVersionTable:PSVersion = 5.1.17763.107